# What is eating the Super+Space shortcut?

Tags: 11.10, shortcut-keys, gnome-do

I used to have Gnome-Do bound to <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> but this stopped working after upgrading to Oneiric. I assume this has something to do with the new Gnome/Compiz combination.

I've looked through both Gnome's and Compiz's shortcuts but can't see anything that would be nixing the keypress.

I've temporarily assigned it to <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> and this works.

Any ideas or do I file this as a bug against Gnome-Do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using GNOME Shell, then mutter eats all <kbd>Super</kbd> keypresses - not just <kbd>Super</kbd> on its own, but *any* keybinding which uses <kbd>Super</kbd>.  Or it did last time I checked.  I need to figure out how to detect this and fall back to something like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.

In Unity, however, <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> should work fine - it does for me ☺.  Although Unity uses just <kbd>Super</kbd> to bring up the Dash, keybindings containing <kbd>Super</kbd> should still work.

Comment: However, you'd need to change/unset the Super key in Unity's plugin options. :-)

Comment: What do you mean?  <super> on its own brings up the dash, but <super>+<space> brings up Do; it works as you'd expect.  At least, it does for me!

Comment: I tried a couple of shortcuts with the Super key and as soon as I press Super, the launcher unhides and the second key doesn't do anything. Or maybe I'm just too slow. :)

Comment: I'm using Gnome Classic with Compiz so no Mutter and no Unity running. I've just set the shortcut back to Super+Space and it works. So very odd. I'll accept this because it's quite informative for other post-Gnome2 nomads like me.