# fcitx won't trigger IME on super+space

Tags: shortcut-keys, fcitx

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

When I just finished installing the sougoupinyin IME with fcitx,Everything works fine.

I want to change the default hotkey combination of Trigger Input Method from L-CTRL + Space
to Super + Space(Win + space) ,so that it make no difference from Microsoft Windows.
The combination do changed to Super + Space , as shown from the Configration panel.
However , the combination won't working.

Found the similar case here [What is eating the Super+Space shortcut?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65907/what-is-eating-the-superspace-shortcut)

Since the desktop of ubuntu 14.04 is based on Unity ,the combination itself  work fine when I use the ibus-based IME previously.

No idea about what to do. My  keyboard layout is English-US.

Sorry for my poor English and formatting.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I just had the same issue on Lubuntu 16.04, and have managed to fix it.

#### The Background

Basically when you change the `Trigger Input Method` variable in the Fcitx Configuration to <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, the display shows it changing to `SUPER_SPACE`, but it actually gets set to `SPACE` (you can still type spaces by using <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>). The Fcitx configuration just changes the files in `~/.config/fcitx`, so you can manually edit them. Look at these lines in `~/.config/fcitx/config`, the TriggerKey has been set to `SPACE` not `SUPER_SPACE`:

`# Trigger Input Method
TriggerKey=SPACE`

#### The Fix

- Manually change Line 3 of `~/.config/fcitx/config` to `TriggerKey=SUPER_SPACE` and save.
- Reopen the Fcitx Configuration tool and apply without changing anything (updates your settings).

That should do it

Comment: In my ubuntu 18.04, the setting in the config file is TriggerKey=SUPER_SPACE by default.  But the key combination still doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

As the comment mentions that in 18.04 and 18.10 the hotkey <kbd>SUPER_SPACE</kbd> does not work.

This can be fixed by unsetting the system hotkey in

> System settings -> Devices -> Keyboard -> Switch to next input source

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 20.04, you can unset the system hotkey in

> Settings -> Keyboard Shortcuts

Answer (score 0):

In my case, after I changed the Trigger input method to <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, I needed to disable the Keyboard shortcuts:

> Settings > Keyboard shortcuts > Switch to next input source >
> [backspace] (to disable the shortcut)

To my understanding, since they're both changing the input, there is either a conflict or double-changing of the input source.